# What is the probability that there are two knights that can attack each other on a 3*3 chessboard...?

Tags: probability, chessboard

What is the probability that there are two knights that can attack each other on a 3*3 chess board if each square contains a knight with 1/2 probability?

Comment: Clearly, the middle square is irrelevant. And, the only way that two knights can attack each other is if a middle square of one side, and a corner of the opposite side are both occupied.

Comment: This is just a simple counting problem. Set up the system nicely and the counting should be straightforward.

Comment: As pointed above, the middle is irrelevant. Consider the other squares in a cyclic list: A1-B3-C1-A2-C3-B1-A3-C2-A1.What is the probability that two adjacent squares in this cycle are both occupied?

Comment: How did you though of using the cyclic structure?

Comment: @mathpadawan: A little playing around on the 3x3 board shows that each non-center square can only attack two others.  That means that those eight squares must either be a single eight-square tour, or a combination of smaller tours.  Either way, a cyclic structure is sought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the middle square is irrelevant.And we want to find the probability that two elements in the cyclic list , $A1-B3-C1-A2-C3-B1-A3-C2-A1$, is adjacent.

We could have any of $A_1,C_1,C_3,A_3$ appear together or any of $B_3,A_2,B_1,C_2$ appear together. Also the 3 coner pieces, then side rows and colums, or any two none of which are the middle square adjacent. That gives a total of $2^4+2^4-1+4+4+8=2^5+16=32+16=47$. So the probability is $\frac{209}{256}$.

Comment: I dont think that's quite correct.  E.g. knights at $A1, A2, A3$ also don't attack each other but you did not count this configuration.

Comment: Thank you! is it correct now?

Comment: By "any two none of which are the middle square adjacent" I presume you mean "any two, one from each of the two halves (of $4$ positions), and the two being non-adjacent", so this number is $8$.  You are almost correct, but you are double-counting the $0$ knight case (which appeared once in each $2^4$ term).  My bigger problem with your approach is that it is not immediately obvious (at least, not to me) that you are not missing cases.  E.g. it took me a bit of thinking to convince myself the "$3$ knights, some from each half" case is fully covered by the corners and edges.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Knightwise" we have a circular graph with $8$ vertices, and on some of these vertices there is a knight. We have to compute the probability $p$ that two adjacent vertices are taken. There are $2^8=256$ equiprobable configurations, and we have to count the configurations containing at least one pair of taken adjacent vertices. These are the *good* configurations.

If there are two knights there are $8$ good configurations, if there are three knights there are $8\cdot 4+8=40$ good configurations, and if there are four knights all configurations except the two regular ones are good, making ${8\choose4}-2=68$ good configurations. All ${8\choose5}+\ldots+{8\choose8}=93$ configurations with $\geq5$ knights are good. Since there are $8+40+68+93=209$ good configurations we obtain
$$p={209\over256}\ .$$

Comment: Just a minor mistake: the number of configs with $\ge 5$ knights is ${1 \over 2} (2^8 - {8 \choose 4})$ instead.

Comment: @antkam: Thank you for spotting and reporting the error.

Comment: Err, Hi sir, why did you have $8*4+8$ for when there are three knights? I know it is the correct count but I'm wondering why did you write it like that?

Comment: @mathpadawan: Two next to each other on $8$ places, and each time $4$ places for the third, or three next to each other on $8$ places.

Answer (score 1):

HINT (in case this is homework)

As many have pointed out you need to count the number of ways knights can populate the $8$-square cycle $A1-B3-C1-A2-C3-B1-A3-C2-A1,$ without any adjacent positions being occupied.  Note that each of the $2^8$ possibilities are equally likely.

I can't think of a one-shot way to count this, but we can certainly count by conditioning on the number of knights.

- If there is $0$ knight, that is $1$ case.
- If there is $1$ knight, then there are no adjacent pair of knights.  The number of ways to do this is ${8 \choose 1}$.
- If there are $2$ knights, then the total number of ways is ${8 \choose 2}$, but you have to subtract all adjacent-pair cases, and there are $X$ of those.
- If there are $3$ knights, this is the hardest case.  However, note that if the $3$ knights are *not* adjacent, then the gaps must be $2-2-1$ or $3-1-1$.  Lets say there are $Y$ of the $2-2-1$ case and $Z$ of the $3-1-1$ case.  Then just add them up.
- If there are $4$ knights, there are only $W$ ways to for them to be non-adjacent.
- If there are $5$ or more knights, there must be an adjacent pair, so these cases contribute nothing to the count.

The total number of ways for a set of knights to be non-adjacent $= 1 + 8 + ({8 \choose 2} - X) + Y + Z + W$.

Comment: $X=8, Y=8, Z=8, W=2$ $X=8$ is because the adjacent pair on the cycle of positions $A1−B3−C1−A2−C3−B1−A3−C2−A1$ is wholly determined by the location of the first knight that you see when you start at a no-knight position and go clockwise on the circle. $Y=8$ is because the one gap in $2-1-1$ gap pattern completely determines the configuration of the placement of the knights and there are eight possible positions in which the one gap could be.  For $Z=8$, the consecutive 3 gaps could start in any of the eight possible positions and go clockwise. And $W=2$ is already listed!

Comment: @mathpadawan - Yup.  Also check out Christian Blatter's alternate way of counting the $3$ knight case.  (Frankly, check out any answer by him, on any question!)